# Why is is python throwing error at the second method in of this class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is is python throwing error at the second method in of this class?

```
class Lutany:
    formulaa = 0
    formulab = 0
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num = num
        self.formulaa = self.formulaA()
        self.formulab = self.formulaB


    def formulaA(self):
        q = 0
        num = self.num
        while num > 0 :
            q += num + (num - 1)
            num = num - 1
        return q
        self.formulab = formulaB()

    def formulaB(self):
        num = self.num
        q = 0
        while num > 0 :
            q = q + (num * num)
            num = num - 1
        return (0.5 * q)


if(__name__ == '__main__'):

    l = Lutany(675)

    p = l.formulaa
    q = l.formulab 

    print " FormunlA returned " , str(p) , "  for 675 "
    print " FormulaB returned " , str(q) , "  for 675 "
```

When running I have the following error:

```
~$ python lutany.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lutany.py", line 30, in <module> 
l = Lutany(675) 
File "lutany.py", line 7, in init 
self.formulab = self.formulaB 
AttributeError: Lutany instance has no attribute 'formulaB'
```

Comment: This is the error:                                                  abdulhakim@abdulhakim-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Python From Dream$ python lutany.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lutany.py", line 30, in <module>
    l = Lutany(675)
  File "lutany.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.formulab = self.formulaB
AttributeError: Lutany instance has no attribute 'formulaB'

Comment: Please include the traceback in the question. Use the edit link under the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing parentheses here: `self.formulab = self.formulaB`. Should be `self.formulab = self.formulaB()`.

Comment: thanks but that is not the problem with the code because even after fixing it the error still persists.

Comment: Thanks. you were right. I copied the code and it now works. though for the life of me i can't understand how my indentation was wrong. :)

Comment: Cool, but Ignacio deserves credit for it, maybe give his answer the green checkbox and upvote both our answers? :)

Answer (score 2):

You've indented the block for the `formulaB()` method too much (although the edit to the question has destroyed evidence of this). Make sure that it is at the indent level directly beneath the class indent, not that of the previous method.

Comment: It is not the problem. The indentations are perfect. the method is being called, it only throws an instance error which i can't fathom why.

Comment: I think this answer is most likely correct (and I upvoted it). That is, that there was an indenting problem. If you copy and paste in the code as it appears right now, you shouldn't get the issue anymore. I tried it and don't get the error.

Comment: Thanks. you were right. I copied the code and it now works. though for the life of me i can't understand how my indentation was wrong. guess I just have to stick with Komodo-Edit :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say, in formalaA `self.formulab = formulaB()` did you mean `self.formulab = self.formulaB()`?